# Gem::LoadError - Ruby on Rails with postgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

I am not even able to get to basic rails landing page. I have gem 'pg' installed and postgreSQL installed but still the following error -

Gem::LoadError
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Rails.root: C:/Sites/simple_cms

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As it says: *Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).* Merely installing it is not enough, it should be bundled with the app.

Comment: Yes I added gem 'pg' and also did bundle but still getting the same error.

Comment: `I added gem 'pg' and also did bundle` Are you sure it was successfully installed? Even on Linux it's not that easy, it requires `libpq-dev` package (in Ubuntu and derivatives at least) do you have something similar?

Comment: I changed my mind now. my purpose to learn RonR not specialize in Postgres or others. So, I decided to build my rails database on sqlite which comes with rails installer. So, far it is going fine. :) Later on I will upload my app to Heroku..